# makebbx - program similar to makebst?

Tags: biblatex, automation, tools, custom-bib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a style definition helper for creating biblatex citation styles, like makebst for biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19429/is-there-a-style-definition-helper-for-creating-biblatex-citation-styles-like-m)

There is a "program" called `makebst` that allows creating of fine-tuned `.bst` files to be read by `bibtex`. This program asks you number of questions regarding the desired format and produces the style.

I would like a similar "program", let's say `makebbx`, that would ask very similar set of questions and produce corresponding `.bbx` (and maybe `.cbx`) files. Does anybody know about such tool?

*Motivation:* I was just about to ask another question of the kind "I want my references look like this with `biblatex`, how do I do that?" Then I discovered that most of the [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) questions are of this kind, which seems to me to be the lack of such tool.