How do I define my own bibliography style file for LaTeX in biblatex?
Courtesy link: Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles

As a general rule, inspect the "Field Formats" section of the file biblatex.def (location: see above). With regard to the example given in your question, look for the following:
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
This means that for @article (and a bunch of other entry types), the title field is put inside quotation marks. (#1 stands for the value of the field, \isdot prevents double punctuation.) In your local biblatex.cfg, change the last part from {\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}} to {#1\isdot}, and you're set with regard to the bibliography. In case your "parent" style prints titles as part of in-text-citations, you'll have to modify the citetitle field in the same way.
For the formatting of citation postnotes, the same principles as above apply, so I'll just post the solution to your actual question. ;-)
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the pages field in the bibliography

How do I define my own bibliography style file for LaTeX by asking a series of questions to customize the style according to my preferences in biblatex?

welcome! as it stands, your question really isn't answerable. we have no idea what style you're trying to implement, what, if anything you've tried, or which obstacles you've encountered. why do you want to create a 'completely custom' style? what problem do you have that you think can best be solved by such a style?

You have two options: start from a blank slate and build up, or take a standard style as s guide and edit as you need. There's no 'right' answer, though I have always done the latter - since it means you have something to work from more easily.

The question is pretty broad, but to get you started, you may want to read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296732/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/719787/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110511/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426387/35864 and linked discussions.

Generally speaking I would say that of the two options Joseph describes, the second one (building upon an existing standard style) is often the better way forward for people new to biblatex, because it gives you a base to build on and allows you to use many useful biblatex idioms and generally makes it more likely that answers on this site are applicable to your code. (But as to how exactly you build upon an existing style, the links from my comment above suggests several options.)

Your new title makes no sense.

As mentioned in Joseph's comment under the accepted answer, you absolutely cannot use makebst with biblatex. makebst generates .bst files (BibTeX style files) for use with classical BibTeX, but biblatex uses a completely different (and completely incompatible) way to specify its style. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330984/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174676/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527274/35864.

There is no makebst equivalent for biblatex (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19429/35864). You will have to write the .bbx and .cbx files required for biblatex yourself. (See the links in my first comment above.)

I suppose that you are looking for the command line tool makebst. This tool guides you through defining your own bibliography style file for LaTeX by asking a series of questions to customize the style according to your preferences.
To use makebst, follow these steps:

Open a terminal or command line interface.
Type latex makebst and press Enter.
The program will ask you questions regarding the formatting and style of your bibliography. For any question where you are unsure of the answer, you can simply press Enter to accept the default setting.

This tool is part of the LaTeX distribution and helps create a .bst file, which is a custom bibliography style file. Once the .bst file is generated, you can use it in your LaTeX document by specifying it with the \bibliographystyle{} command.

This will not work with biblatex

Oh you are right. Did not know that. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19429/is-there-a-makebst-like-style-definition-helper-for-creating-biblatex-styles
